# How to make a table with PyQt 3.3.6?

Tags: python, pyqt, python-2.4

I don't have access to the designer. I'm able to make a list (but that can only have one column). I tried QTableView and QListView and basically everything I could find on the internet (though it's all geared towards PyQt 4), and nothing worked. My latest attempt was QGridView, which yields the error:

"qt.QGridView represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated"

The code:

```
from qt import *
class main_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        apply(QMainWindow.__init__, (self,) + args)
        self.mainWidget = QWidget(self);
        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget, 10, 5)

        self.table = QGridView(self.mainWidget)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table)

def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    win = main_window()
    win.show()
    app.connect(app, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), app.quit)
    app.exec_loop()
```

Comment: QtGui.QTableView should do the trick.  You'll need to provide some code of what you are trying to do in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: That gives me 'global name 'QtGui' is not defined'

Comment: @JonKaplan. Wow, PyQt-3.3.6? That's almost thirteen years old! Why the heck are you still using that? If you can't upgrade, you'll have to use a [QTable](http://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qtable.html). However, I vaguely recall that this could be a bit buggy, so don't expect too much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck using this -- no choice! I've also already tried QTable with 'self.table = QTable(self.mainWidget)'.

It tells me 'global name 'QTable' is not defined' :(

Comment: @JonKaplan. Hm, it's starting to come back to me now. The table classes are possibly in a separate module: `qttable`, perhaps?

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKED! Thank you SO much. I've been stuck on this for longer than I'd care to admit, and the internet is absolutely useless on 13-year-old things. Thanks again.

Comment: @JonKaplan. Amazing. If you're lucky, you might still be able to find source code packages for PyQt-3.3.6, which will contain docs, examples and some tutorials. The [PyQt Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) might also have some older stuff, but probably a lot of the links are dead by now.

Comment: @JonKaplan at a certain point, manually backporting and installing newer versions of software becomes *much* easier than trying to support the obsolete version. It looks to me like you're at that point. I wouldn't even use Qt4 these days, since Qt5 is much more friendly in a lot of ways (but most Qt4 code is ported to Qt5 more easily than Qt3 -> Qt4 was)